# Hibernate date don't save the milliseconds

Tags: java, hibernate, timestamp

I'm saving an entity in hibernate with a creation date

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "dtcreation")
    @Type(type="timestamp")
    private Date creation;
```

and I put a new Date on this field:

```
    entity.setCreation(new Date());
    entityDao.persist(entity);
```

but when it is saved on the db the time don't contains the milliseconds, but put it a 0
if I try to update with a query the value of the milliseconds it works...someone can help me?

after the persist method i have a record with 01/06/2011 15:00:00.0
but if i made an UPDATE i can change the milliseconds, so the db supports it..
the database is informix

Comment: java.util.Date is quite old and horrible. If you can, investigate Joda Time instead. It integrates with Hibernate. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html

Comment: i guess your main issue is the DB column you save into (not the date impl, i've never had issues w/ java.util.Date)

Comment: I doubt this is an hibernate issue. What's the underlying database?

Comment: Your last sentence is jumbled-up and confusing, I'd edit it but I don't want to mess it up if my interpretation is wrong. If you could clarify your description of what happens, that would be helpful.

Comment: Which DB are you using? Are you sure you use the right Dialect?

Comment: I bet he is using MSSQL server, and the underlying coulumn type is datetime.

Comment: Show us the code for the EntityDao persist method. I am guessing something is overwriting the new Date() value you put into the creation field.

Comment: I think too it's something to do a DB or JDBC jar. I very recently worked on hibernate project where were using hibernate and java.util.Date. Didn't have problems with milliseconds. The DB was postgres

Answer (score 10):

This is consistent with the documented behavior of [java.util.Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [java.sql.Timestamp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

java.util.Date stores down to the second, and java.sql.Timestamp is a thin wrapper to accommodate the nanosecond value of a SQL timestamp value. If you read the note on the Timestamp javadoc, it clearly states this difference.

If you don't want to lose your second fractions, and don't want to investigate alternative date libraries (e.g. the aforementioned Joda Time) you'll need to make the field a java.sql.Timestamp, and use the milisecond value of the current date to construct the initial value

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
entity.setCreation(timestamp);
```

Comment: How do you have the entity? Hibernate not save de milliseconds :S

Answer (score 0):

Without your code to test it's difficult for me to definitively answer, but in taking a look at the Javadoc for [java.sql.Timestamp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), it appears that you're mixing types with annotating the field as a timestamp.  Change the java type from Date to Timestamp and see if that solves your problem.